# Why does secant method converge

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

Assume $f$ is continuous and twice differentiable on $[a,b]$ such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$, $x \in [a,b]$.

If $f(b)>0$ and $f(a)<0$ and I choose $x_0=a$,why are we gauraunteed convergence with the iterations:

$$x_n=x_{n-1}-f(x_{n-1})\frac{b-x_{n-1}}{f(b)-f(x_{n-1})}$$

I made some progress, but it relies on an assumption that I don't know how to prove.

I assume that $x_k$ is bounded above by the root. Meaning if $f(\xi)=0$ then $\xi>x_k$ for all $k$.

What I did:

$x_{k+1}=x_k-f(x_k)\frac{b-x_k}{f(b)-f(x_k)}$

Notice that our initial $x_0$ was $a$, and $f(a) <0$. we also assumed $x_k < \xi$ and that $f$ is continuous and $f'(x)>0$, it follows that $f(x_k)<f(\xi)=0$. We also know that $b-x_k >0$ (again, from the assumption on $\xi$) and that $f(b)-f(x_k)>0$. This is because $f$ is monotonic rising and continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(b)>0$. It follows that $f(b)>f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

So overall, the term $-f(x_k)\frac{b-x_k}{f(b)-f(x_k)}$ is positive. and so $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha$ where $\alpha>0$ and so $x_{k+1}>x_k$ and the sequence is monotonic rising.

Since we also assumed it is bounded by $\xi$, it converges. We still need to prove it converges to $\xi$:

Let's call the limit $L$:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}x_{k}=\lim_{k \to \infty}x_{k+1}=L$$

$L=L-f(L)\frac{b-L}{f(b)-f(L)}$, it follows that $f(L)\frac{b-L}{f(b)-f(L)}=0$

We assumed $x_k$ is bounded by $\xi$. This means that $L \leq \xi <b$. So $L \neq b$.

This indeed implies $f(L)=0$, since there is only one root, this means $L=\xi$.

End of proof.

All of this fails because we rely on the assumption $x_k \leq \xi$.
How do I prove this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first guess is $x_0=a$ and $f(a)<0$. Because $f$ is convex

$$\frac{f(x_1)-f(a)}{x_1-a}< \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

With this you can prove $f(x_1)<0$ and $x_1 < \xi$.

Note that

$$f(x_1) < f(a) + \frac{x_1-a}{b-a}[f(b)-f(a)]= f(a)-\frac{f(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}[f(b)-f(a)]=0$$

On each subsequent iteration you start with $f(x_i) <0$ and consequently you get $f(x_{i+1})<0$ and $x_{i+1}< \xi$.